# How to convert a label into a countdown timer value

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, type-conversion, logic

I have a little doubt about converting a variable.

this is my situation = I have a label (as numbers like time limit) but I have to convert this label into a int variable because I need to do a regressive timer with that value (like a "Time left" timer).

I'm kinda confuse 'cause I tried to convert my string into int using the normal parameter

int "value" = Convert.ToInt32(lblNumber)

(and then, this lblNumber would be a time value like "03:45:30")

and I didn't get any results from this. My Label still has an "static" value. 
It isn't working as a "display" to show how much time left I have.

well, the label was supposed to show this:

"03:39:55"
"03:39:54"
"03:39:53"

and there it goes, as a countdown.

Comment: int foo = Int.Parse(lblNumber.Text);

Comment: Also those are times, not integers.  So if your label has the value "03:39:55" and you try to parse it into an integer, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this "times" are shown in a label as a ".text" format, and I want to convert the numbers (excluding the ":") into a int variable. That's why I made this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this, have a look and see if it helps you

```html
      
        decimal vals = 0.1m;
        decimal minute = 60m; //both are at the class level

      private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //here is where i enabled and started my timer;
            //i just dragged a timer over my form in the (design) area

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

            list.Add(richTextBox1.Text.ToString());//ignore this line
           

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //the tick interval is set to 100
            //which is 0.1 seconds
            minute = minute - vals;
            string aaa = minute.ToString();
            label3.Text = aaa;
            if (minute == 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to be accessing the `Text` property of your `Label` to achieve your desired results. `lblNumber` is exactly what it is, a `Label` object, not the string that your `Label` is display.

Read More:
[WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx)
[WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(v=vs.110).aspx)